# Adding an element before particular value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, loops, java-stream

I need to add an element before every occurrence of a particular element. I can do this using for loop and calculate the index and then add the element. Is there any efficient method without using for loop or using streams.

e.g: `int[] a = {1,2,4,5,7,9,2,5}`
Add element **{3}** before every occurrence of 2 which result in **{1,3,2,4,5,7,9,3,2,5}**

Attempt:

```
int[] a =  {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 2, 5};
            int[] new1 = null;
            int[] indexToAdd = IntStream.range(0, a.length)
                      .filter(i -> a[i] == 2)
                      .map(i -> i) 
                      .toArray();
            for(int j = 0; j<indexToAdd.length; j++){
                final Integer innerj = new Integer(j);
                new1 = IntStream.range(0,a.length)
                        .map(i -> {
                            if (i < indexToAdd[innerj]) {
                                return a[i];
                            } else if (i == indexToAdd[innerj]) {
                                return 3 ;
                            } else {
                                return a[i - 1];
                            }
                        }).toArray();
            }
```

Comment: Can you show us your (possibly inefficient) effort?

Comment: You could do it more efficiently if it was already sorted first ;-)

Comment: You can't do this without a loop because the fastest solution is `O(n)`. Unless you mean you don't want to implement the loop yourself.

Comment: @deHaar - Added the effort which i tried.

Comment: @Druckles- cant sort it, because this will actually be a byte array from a channel so cant manipulate it.

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient way is to create another array on the fly so that we always add elements at the end which is O(1) as compared to adding elements somewhere in the middle of the array which is O(n):

```java
    int[] arr1 = {1,2,4,5,7,9,2,5};
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i < arr1.length; i++)
    {
      int elem = arr1[i];
      if(elem == 2)
      {
        list2.add(3);
      }
      list2.add(elem);
    }
    
    Integer[] arr2 = list2.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    arr1 = Arrays.stream(integers).mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
```

Another 1 liner using streams:

```java
    int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 2, 5};
    arr1 = Arrays.stream(arr1)
        .flatMap(x -> x == 2 ? Stream.of(3, x).mapToInt(i -> i) : Stream.of(x).mapToInt(i -> i))
        .toArray();
```

Comment: How is this related to an array?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Why `Integer[]` ? and maybe OP want solution `without using for loop`

Comment: Updated the code to convert it back to int from Integer. Am not sure if OP wants that and if its even possible.

Comment: I also doubt there's an efficient way without a loop or streaming...

Comment: I added a streams solution also.